# Yarn Build: Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: linux, build, hadoop-yarn

Help please. I have been suffering for 5 days.

In 1 folder I write yarn build and everything is successful!!
There is an error in the second folder

I'm trying to install the script, but I'm stuck at the last stage. Help.

```
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/shops?limit=100&is_active=1',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'coderead.xyz',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'https://coderead.xyz/shops?limit=100&is_active=1',
    _timeout: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 92.51.46.114:443
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
    errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '92.51.46.114',
    port: 443
  }
}

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /authors/[shopSlug]
    at C:\Users\admin\Downloads\pixer-laravel\shop\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:991:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Install script

I'm trying to install the script, but I'm stuck at the last stage. Help.
I'm trying to install the script, but I'm stuck at the last stage. Help.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xbSRHkfM22/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.